# Impala or Hive?

Tags: mapreduce, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, impala

**Situation** - 
approximately 30 million rows per day, 2 years worth of data in Impala managed tables in CDH 5.2 cluster (16 nodes, shared cluster).

Trying to put together a daily aggregation logic, for which one days data is brought in and aggregated, and the process repeated over and over again for subsequent days. (through impala)

This is a one time process, to be done to create the aggregates for the whole 2 year window, subsequently consumed by other tools.

I am wondering, if the tool choice is really the right one here ? Shouldn't we leverage the cluster's power by giving this job to hive (so that it triggers mapreduce and aggregation can be done relatively easily) ?

[Edit]

Just to clarify, the data is already on Impala tables, and the aggregation i am referring to is being done on top of that.  What i am thinking from solution point of view is, would it be better to give this data to hive tables (instead of impala tables) and then let map-reduce take care of aggregations ?

The impala based aggregation is really slow for us, though we are looking into tuning it, i wonder if we could do something diff ?

Answer (score 3):

Ingestion is done as you say via hive - but impala will give you order(/s) of magnitude better read performance. So consider that your analytics stack could work atop impala while your ETL would remain on hive.

In any case the load/ETL time is not user-facing whereas the analytics/queries do have the latency-critical characteristic.

Comment: well, impala in my situation is not coming back with the aggregation, not at all.  thats why i m exploring other options ?

Comment: You would need to look into the query itself and tune it.   Using hive will only slow that down further.

Comment: Consider the ETL in impala as well. There are various parsing and conversion functions in impala that are usable in ETL process especially in impala 2.6.0 and higher. Also; consider using impala-parquet together definitely. You will see an increase at the read and aggregation performance. After the table creation, consider using compute (or "incremental" if table is very large) stats. This will positively effect the read performance as well.